# encode and decode issue in php

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps

i'm working on php, i need to convert an array to javascript array.How to change?
Please help below is my output value.

I am trying from long time to debug but not getting any leads.

my php code:

```
<?php
  include "db_connection.php";
  $locations=array();
      $query =  $conn->query('SELECT `pg_address` FROM `tbl_master_property` limit 10');
       while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
         $locations[] = $row;
      }
      $locations = json_encode($locations);
      //echo "<pre>";print_r($locations);die;
?>
```

Array php value output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [pg_address] =>  # 3/20, 1st Main, 1st Cross, Hosur Main Road, Adugodi, Bangalore
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [pg_address] =>  24/3 Bazaar Street, Adugodi, Bangalore - 560030
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [pg_address] => # 430, Koramangala 7th Block, Beside Sai Baba Temple, Bangalore
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [pg_address] => # 41, 1st Cross, 2nd Main, Behind M R Granite, Adugodi, Bannerghatta Main Road, Bangalore
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [pg_address] =>  # 27, 2nd Main, B cross, Nanjappa Layout, Adugodi, opp. to Vijaya Bank, Bangalore
        )

)
```

Javascript code:

```
var locations = <?= $locations ?>;
```

//---I need a format like this in js ----//

```
var locations = [
           '3/20, 1st Main, 1st Cross, Hosur Main Road, Adugodi, Bangalore',
           '24/3 Bazaar Street, Adugodi, Bangalore - 560030',
           '# 430, Koramangala 7th Block, Beside Sai Baba Temple, Bangalore',
           '# 41, 1st Cross, 2nd Main, Behind M R Granite, Adugodi, Bannerghatta Main Road, Bangalore',
           '# 27, 2nd Main, B cross, Nanjappa Layout, Adugodi, opp. to Vijaya Bank, Bangalore'  
  ];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your php while loop change below line.

```
$locations[] = $row['pg_address'];
```

Try this check if it works? Also your question is not very clear, but this may help you.

Comment: thank you so much sir it's working fine ,,,,i need to pass name also how will pass same array.

Answer (score 0):

This code may work for you:

```
array_push($locations,json_encode($row['pg_address']));
```

Comment: yaa it's working fine sir i need name & address also for google marker popup toolkit

Answer (score 0):

Use `json_encode` PHP function to encode your data and assign into Javascript variable that will give you desired output array, your updated code will look like this

```
<?php
  include "db_connection.php";
  $locations=array();
      $query =  $conn->query('SELECT `pg_address` FROM `tbl_master_property` limit 10');
       while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
         $locations[] = $row['pg_address'];
      }
?>
```

In javascript,

`var locations = <?php echo json_encode($locations) ?>;`

Hope this helps.

Comment: yaa it's working fine sir i need name & address also for google marker popup toolkit